# In google documents, is there a reason why a calendar events are not insertable as smart chips?

Tags: google-docs, google-calendar

I'm editor of a company Google Document, and I want to insert in that document events from a Google Calendar (for which I'm owner) which is also shared to the whole company. Notice this is a secondary calendar, not my user one.
Unfortunatly, for reasons I can't understand, this calendar events are not visible (and I can't find them) in the document by typing `@` followed by event title.

Are there any permission mechanisms preventing that use cas ?

Comment: Please checkout the resources for end-users. Start looking from the Help menu. Add what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. Please bear in mind that Google use "calendar" instead of "agenda".

Comment: @Rubén I fixed name usage. And I've already searched the document and found absolutely no information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Insert smart chips & building blocks in your Google Doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10710316?hl=en) doesn't mention anything about other calendars than the user calendar so it's look that what you are looking to happen is not a supported feature.

A "hack" that you might try is to invite yourself. This might make that the event  appear also in your calendar.

Please consider to send your feedack directly to Google by clicking on the Help menu on the Google Docs editor toolbar, then clik **Help Docs Improve** and follow the on screen instructions.

*Screenshot of the Google Docs Editor with the Help menu expanded and the Help Docs Improve option highlighted.*

[image: Help Docs Improve]